# Displaying multiple images from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a numpy array (data.npy) which stores multiple sample images. I want to view/ save all the images. I have tried following:

```
img_array=np.load('data.npy')
i = 0
while i < len(img_array):
   plt.imshow(img_array[i], cmap='gray')
   plt.show()
   i += 1
```

but this gives an error:

```
TypeError: Invalid dimensions for image data
```

Comment: What you have is a binary file, not an array.  How you extract the data from it depends on how it was stored when the file was created.  What is the shape of `img_array`?

Comment: @ChrisMueller shape of img_array is : (22, 4, 100, 100)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @John Zwinck's answer, the following code seems to be working fine for me.

```
In [12]: for idx, el in enumerate(img_array):
    ...:     plt.imshow(np.moveaxis(img_array[idx], 0, -1), cmap='gray')
    ...:
```

`np.moveaxis` moves around the axis of an array. Here it shifts the first axis in the original array to the last axis.

```
In [13]: a[10].shape
Out[13]: (4, 100, 100)

In [14]: np.moveaxis(a[10], 0, -1).shape
Out[14]: (100, 100, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a `(4,100,100)` array to `imshow()` but the docs say it requires the channel dimension to come last: http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

So use `moveaxis()` or `rollaxis()` to change the order of the dimensions: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html